# Regex allows extra characters

Tags: c#, regex

When trying to write a Regex expression in C#, the Regex itself is correct and matches the string:

```
String telRegex = @"(^0[0-9]{10})|(\(0[0-9]{4}\)[0-9]{6}$)";
Match telRegexResult = Regex.Match(textBox1.Text, telRegex);
if (telRegexResult.Success) {
    MessageBox.Show("Your Regex Matches!");
} else MessageBox.Show("Your Regex doesn't match!");
```

If I put "01446847362" it will show that the regex matches, which is the intended outcome, but if I also put "01446847362word", it'll also show that it is correct.

Is there anything I can add to my regex to make it cut off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex includes an alternation, which means it captures either:

```
^0[0-9]{10}
```

Or:

```
\(0[0-9]{4}\)[0-9]{6}$
```

You'll note therefore that neither side includes *both* the `^` start of line and `$` end of line matches, which is what you require to ensure that the entire string is matched.

Try the following, which moves the `^` and `$` outside the alternation (which is now within its own group):

```
String telRegex = @"^((0[0-9]{10})|(\(0[0-9]{4}\)[0-9]{6}))$";
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use [conditional matching with expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions#Conditional_Expr). Although the length of pattern is the same as @Iridium's one, this shows that there are always several ways to do the same thing in Regex:

```
string pattern = @"^0(?'p'\()?[0-9]{4}(?('p')\))[0-9]{6}$";
```